# Android Lollipop WebView Load URL Issue

Tags: webview, android-5.0-lollipop

When I am loading a URL in WebView for Android Lollipop 5.0, it shows a popup to choose a browser instead of showing the content in WebView itself. The same code was working fine in all earlier versions. What might be causing this?

[image]

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: Hi there, I touched up your question's grammar and asked a question for you. You didn't ask a question, actually. Oops. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Drakes. Can you please suggest me, if you have idea regarding this issue. Actually this issue is coming, when I am enabling Java Script in WebView. In my case I bound to enable Java Script in Web View, because some Java script code is there in Web Page which I am opening.

Comment: Hello, apologies, but I just popped in to touch up your question to help you. Android isn't my area. Hmm... to attract more attention to this good question, maybe add a code snippet and things you've tried, or a possible guess at why this is happening. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webLink);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(url);
```